# How do I debug an iisnode application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iisnode

I have several iisnode applications running on a server. They all have application pools, web.config, and server.js.  They all work, except for one.

Our internal DNS is setup to recognize this URL.

I've been over the web.config and server.js files and can't find any reason for the application to not load.  If I run 'ng serve --port 3500' - it will appear on localhost:3500 so the application is ok.
if I run 'node server.js' the application loads on port 8090 (as per the server.js file).

If I'm running 'node server.js' the application won't load via the URL, but will run via *servername*:8090

server.js

```
var serverType = 'AM-LMS EDITOR';
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8090;

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization");
    next();
    });


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/am-lms-admin'));

//body parse
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb',extended: true }))


// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}))
app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));


app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('/dist/am-lms-admin/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

// Handle 404
app.use(function(req, res) {
    //res.send(‘404: Page not Found’, 404);
    res.status(404).send({status:404, message: '404 Not Found', type:'client'}); 
   });

/// Handle 500
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send({status:500, message: 'internal error', type:'internal'}); 
   });

//listen
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port,() => console.log(serverType +' server running on port: '+ port));
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit below link

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a node.js application
        to be handled by the iisnode module -->
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
       <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="amlgm\cclark, amlgm\tknoob, amlgm\tnakagawa, amlgm\csnyder, amlgm\rcarter" />

                
                
                

            </authorization>
    </security>
    
    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
     <!-- <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
      <remove statusCode="401" />
      <error statusCode="401" errorMode="Detailed"/>
    </httpErrors> -->

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you ping the URL and get a response? If not, then either the ping port is blocked or the DNS doesn't have the URL configured correctly.

Comment: If ping works, then try hosting a static webpage at the URL. Does the static webpage load? If not, this hints at a problem in the Apache/Nginx config.

Comment: Yes - the url pings

Comment: Pinging servername.local [10.20.1.97] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.20.1.97: bytes=32 time=72ms TTL=127

Comment: iisnode has a directory under the root of all the applications that creates a file each time the application is accessed. 

This application has the directory, but it doesn't generate any files.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error: 

am-lms-admin/:1 GET http://am-lms-admin/ 500 (Internal Server Error)